# How to shorten Exception Handling Message in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, exception, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on a Rails project and using Exceptions Handling in it, I am using it like this:

```
    begin
        @profile.update(profile_params)
        flash[:success] = SUCCESS_MESSAGE_FOR_PROFILE_UPDATED 
        redirect_to params[:referrer]
    rescue => e
        flash[:alert] = "#{e.message}"
        render :edit
    end
```

When exception occurs, it generates a very long message:

```
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_companies_on_name" DETAIL: Key (name)=(Test2) already exists. : UPDATE "companies" SET "name" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "companies"."id" = $3
```

As we can see that the exception occurred due to duplicate entry for 'name',   so basically I just want to show the **DETAIL** part i.e. "**Key (name)=(Test2) already exists.**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have, is a database level validation (constraint), which is good.

In addition to it you always want to add the model validation.

In your case it'll look as follows:

```
validates :name, uniqueness: true
```

It will ensure the validation and appropriate message, when

```
@profile.update(profile_params)
```

fails to update the record due to validation.

The message could be found in `@profile.errors`.

With such setup you will not need to have a `begin rescue`, just change it to:

```
if @profile.update(profile_params)
  flash[:success] = SUCCESS_MESSAGE_FOR_PROFILE_UPDATED
  redirect_to params[:referrer]
else
  render :edit
end
```

The form will contain the validation error out of the box.

Comment: hats off to you